# Why does WordPress add 0 (zero) to an Ajax response?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, ajax

Unless I end Ajax processing function by `exit()` or `die()`, the Ajax function receives desired and correct output but following by `0`.

Any idea why is that happening?

Is that meant to be like that or it could be fixed?

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_homepage', 'get_homepage');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_homepage', 'get_homepage');

function get_homepage(){
    echo "get_homepage ->";
    exit();
}
```

I've read at [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), but why is that necessary?

Comment: Does it (the addition of 0) happen even if you're logged out of wordpress?

Comment: Yes, even if I am not logged into WordPress.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The default response from `admin-ajax.php` is,

`die( '0' );`

...by adding your own `wp_die()` or `exit()` or `die()` after returning your desired content prevents the default response from `admin-ajax.php` being returned as well.

It also generally means that your ajax call has succeeded.

Ultimately, to answer your question, it's meant to work this way. What you are doing by exiting after returning your content is the right thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So do I use die() or I check inside ajax for 0 to know that everything was ok?

Comment: Use `die()` or `exit()` after you echo your content/data. In the `success/complete` callback function of your ajax method, you can then manipulate the data and use it to populate the DOM. You can also do any additional error checking to validate data integrity. You can also do error checking in your PHP callback function prior to output. Essentially exiting after returning your response will ensure you don't also get the `0` along with it. By the way just because you receive a `0` response does not mean your ajax call was 100% successful. However its easy to tell when you inspect your output.

Comment: You should be using `wp_die()` added in 2.0.4

Comment: @thrillcode unless you need to expose the process of `wp_die` to other plugins or theme code that can hook onto said process, then, using `die` or `exit` is ok. If you intend to release your code as OSS or otherwise, where your code needs to play nice with others, then `wp_die` would be more preferable, agreed.