# AJAX: admin-ajax.php is adding extra content to my script's response - how to exclude header, footer, etc.?

Tags: ajax

I am requesting something using WP AJAX through admin-ajax.php .

But I've noticed, that response from my ajax hook is modified by admin-ajax.php - it buffers the hook function output and posts back the whole HTML tree - the whole template, including header, footer, content template....

Is there a cleaner way how to request ONLY content outputted by the hook function than wrapping header, footer, etc. in conditions?

**EDIT - REPRODUCED CODE:**

**HTML & JS in frontend display PHP file**

```
  <div id="ajaxTester">AT</div>
  <script>
  $('#ajaxTester').click( function(){
    //!!!HERE WAS A MISTAKE - MISSING "ECHO" BEFORE "admin_url"!!!
    $.post( '<?php admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', { "action" : "myAjaxFunc" }, function( data ){
      $('body').append( data );
    } );
  } );
  </script>
```

**Added to functions.php**

```
  function myAjaxFunc(){
    //... some output
    echo "some output";    
  }
  add_action("wp_ajax_myAjaxFunc", "myAjaxFunc");
```

**Note:** it seems like it's taking the output as a post and trying to push it through theme template...

### EDIT2 - found it:

**I forgot to put `echo` before `admin_url('admin-ajax.php');`** so it was requesting home page and sice homepage was using function to display also first few posts, it "worked",

Now only extra-content problem left is that it's adding 0 code after the output - this was   actually solved here already:

[Why does WordPress add 0 (zero) to an Ajax response?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116759/why-does-wordpress-add-0-zero-to-an-ajax-response)

Comment: What you describe is not done by `admin-ajax.php` as default. Can you post your code?

Comment: You code doesn't say much. With that info your problem can not be reproduces. Please, add all the relevant code or we can not help you.

Comment: If that is all the relevant code, I think nobody here can tell you why your ajax request is loading footer, header and so on because we can not reproduce the issue. You say "maybe the function is ....", who knows, post the code.

Comment: You see, you posted the code and we can see the problem, including you. ;)

Comment: @cybmeta I did and I found out a very silly mistake :) , Thank you very much though, because you made me reproduce the problem myself, I wouldn't find it without it.

Comment: By the way, you forget to `die()` or `exit()` at the end of `myAjaxFunc()` after the output is sending out.

Comment: Well that one wasn't "forget" thing - i just haven't done it yet - I've already posted solution link :) Thanks again.